# Convergence of a sequence in the sense of $\mathfrak{L}^{\text{loc}}_{1}(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, functional-analysis, limits

Define $w_{n}\in \mathfrak{L}^{\text{loc}}_{1}(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$ such that

$$w_{n}(t)=\begin{cases}0, & |t|<n, \\ n, & |t|\ge n.\end{cases}$$

I want to prove that $w_{k}$ converges to the zero function in the sense of  $\mathfrak{L}^{\text{loc}}_{1}(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$.

By definition, $\{w_{k}\}$ converges to the zero function, in the sense of  $\mathfrak{L}^{\text{loc}}_{1}(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$, if $\forall a,b\in\mathbb{R}$,

$$\lim_{k\to\infty}\int_{a}^{b}\|0-w_{k}(t)\|dt=0$$

i.e. $$\lim_{k\to\infty}\int_{a}^{b}\|w_{k}(t)\|dt=0$$

What actually needs to be done here? Since $w_{k}(t)=0$ if $|t|<k$ and if we let $k\to\infty$ then it's only consequential that $w_{k}(t)\to 0$.

Comment: Basically you are done. For proper proof-writing: Fix $a < b$. Then, there exists one $k_0\in\mathbb N$ such that $-k_0 < a < b < k_0$ and so on... :)

Comment: @user251257 What do you do with the $k_{0}$ exactly?

Comment: you want say when $w_k(t) = 0$ for all $t\in(a,b)$

Comment: @user251257 So fixing $a<b$, $\exists k\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $-k_{0}<a<b<k_{0}$ when $w_{k}(t)=0$ since $|t|<k_{0}$ for all $t\in(a,b)$. Thus $w_{k}(t)\to 0$ as $k\to\infty$?

Comment: Wait. I will just write an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you are done. Just for proper proof-writing:

Fix $a < b$. Then, there exists a $k_0\in \mathbb N$ with $-k_0 < a < b < k_0$. Thus, for every $k\ge k_0$ and $t\in(a,b)$ it follows
$$ w_k(t) = 0 $$ 
and
$$ \int_a^b \|w_k(t) \| \;\mathrm dt = 0. $$
That is,
$$ \lim_{k\to\infty} \int_a^b \|w_k(t) \| \;\mathrm dt = 0. $$